# How to select first fifth columns split by tab from a text file without header in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

The sample data looks like:

> value1     value2     value3     value4     value5     value6

I used `Import-Csv | Format-Table` to get the data, but the column can't split by tab. I’ve tried `` -Delimiter "`t" ``, but still cannot split.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

For "whitespace" separated values (tab,space)

```
(Get-Content C:\temp\Book1.csv).Split()
```

For comma separated values (or any other for that case)

```
(Get-Content C:\temp\Book1.csv).Split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not tab. This is just space. Share your sample file so that we can address it. For the above mentioned value, you can just use split and either pick it with array index or you can use `Select-String` to pick the corresponding value.

```
$a="value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6"

$a.Split(' ') | Select-String value5

$a.Split(' ')[4]
```

**Output:**

> value5
>
> value5

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need to make tab between value1 to value 2. This is my code sir `Import-Csv` `-Delimiter "`t"` | `Select "Person ID","Time"' | 'Format-Table` |`Out-File .csv`

Comment: Still I am not clear. So you want to insert tab between your values while reading the csv file? Then modify your question since its not what you are expecting in the question. Show your sample of the file and what is your expected output, so that we can isolate.

Comment: my boss asked me to create a tab between person ID and time, i chose but i can't create tab between columns. now it's just a space between person ID and time. **Expected output** > B05 <tab> 06:44:31